# Hide a div with specific class in nested DOM structure

Tags: html, css

I want to add a border to the first div of following DOM only. But the border applies to all the divs.

```
<li class="x-tree-node">
    <div ext:tree-node-id="xnode-6" class="x-tree-node-el x-unselectable x-tree-node-expanded" unselectable="on">
    </div>
    <ul class="x-tree-node-ct">
        <li class="x-tree-node">
            <div ext:tree-node-id="xnode-17" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-icon"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon gx-tree-layer-icon" unselectable="on">
                <input class="x-tree-node-cb" type="checkbox" checked="">
            </div>
            <ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul>
        </li>
        <li class="x-tree-node">
            <div ext:tree-node-id="xnode-16" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-icon"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon gx-tree-layer-icon" unselectable="on">
                <input class="x-tree-node-cb" type="checkbox" checked="">
            </div>
            <ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul>
        </li>
        <li class="x-tree-node">
            <div ext:tree-node-id="xnode-15" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-icon"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon gx-tree-layer-icon" unselectable="on">
                <input class="x-tree-node-cb" type="checkbox" checked="">
            </div>
            <ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul>
        </li>
        <li class="x-tree-node">
            <div ext:tree-node-id="xnode-14" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-icon"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon gx-tree-layer-icon" unselectable="on">
                <input class="x-tree-node-cb" type="checkbox" checked="">
            </div>
            <ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul>
        </li>
        <li class="x-tree-node">
            <div ext:tree-node-id="xnode-13" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable " unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-icon"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow-end"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon gx-tree-layer-icon" unselectable="on">
                <input class="x-tree-node-cb" type="checkbox" checked="">
            </div>
            <ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I tried following approaches. None of those worked for me.

```
.x-tree-node-el:nth-child(1){
    border: 1px solid red;
}
/*
.x-tree-node-el ~ .x-tree-node-el {
    border: none;
}*/

/*
#layerTree > .x-tree-node div:first-of-type {
    display: none;
}*/
/*
#layerTree li.x-tree-node > div{ 
    display: none;
}

#layerTree li.x-tree-node > div ~ div {
    display: block;
}*/

/*.x-tree-node-el:first-of-type{ display:none; }*/
```

It must be a CSS only solution. Any help?

Comment: You need this class "x-tree-node-el" in every div inside your list elements?

Comment: Yes, I need it in every div. Unfortunately I can't change the DOM structure and attributes, classes.

Comment: Why don't you remove the border for all nested elements `.x-tree-node-el .x-tree-node-el { border: none }`;

Comment: @KilianStinson it add border to all divs. 
.x-tree-node-el{
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.x-tree-node-el .x-tree-node-el { border: none };

Comment: @LalindaSampath my fault, misread your html. I thought the divs are nested. Added an answer with the `ul` class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the HTML displayed is not wrapped in another `ul` with the same class as `.x-tree-node-ct`

```
.x-tree-node-el { border: 1px solid red; } 
.x-tree-node-ct .x-tree-node-el { border: 0 }
```

This removes all borders from elements within `.x-tree-node-ct`

Working [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/pohnspvr/) with your example code

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
.x-tree-node-ct li:first-child div:first-child {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mpznd2pp/5/

Comment: Can't change anything in DOM structure.

Comment: @LalindaSampath Now is with your structure :)

Comment: it should be first div with parent li.

Answer (score 1):

Try like below.

```
.x-tree-node-ct li.x-tree-node:first-child div.x-tree-node-el {
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mpznd2pp/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.x-tree-node-el:not(.x-tree-node-leaf){
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```css
.x-tree-node-el:not(.x-tree-node-leaf){
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<li class="x-tree-node">
  <div ext:tree-node-id="xnode-6" class="x-tree-node-el x-unselectable x-tree-node-expanded" unselectable="on">
  </div>
  <ul class="x-tree-node-ct">
    <li class="x-tree-node">
      <div ext:tree-node-id="xnode-17" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-icon"></span>
        <img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="
        class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow">
        <img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon gx-tree-layer-icon" unselectable="on">
        <input class="x-tree-node-cb" type="checkbox" checked="">
      </div>
      <ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul>
    </li>
    <li class="x-tree-node">
      <div ext:tree-node-id="xnode-16" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-icon"></span>
        <img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="
        class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow">
        <img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon gx-tree-layer-icon" unselectable="on">
        <input class="x-tree-node-cb" type="checkbox" checked="">
      </div>
      <ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul>
    </li>
    <li class="x-tree-node">
      <div ext:tree-node-id="xnode-15" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-icon"></span>
        <img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="
        class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow">
        <img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon gx-tree-layer-icon" unselectable="on">
        <input class="x-tree-node-cb" type="checkbox" checked="">
      </div>
      <ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul>
    </li>
    <li class="x-tree-node">
      <div ext:tree-node-id="xnode-14" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-icon"></span>
        <img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="
        class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow">
        <img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon gx-tree-layer-icon" unselectable="on">
        <input class="x-tree-node-cb" type="checkbox" checked="">
      </div>
      <ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul>
    </li>
    <li class="x-tree-node">
      <div ext:tree-node-id="xnode-13" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable " unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-icon"></span>
        <img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="
        class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow-end">
        <img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon gx-tree-layer-icon" unselectable="on">
        <input class="x-tree-node-cb" type="checkbox" checked="">
      </div>
      <ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```